# Why is Flask only creating one table when I have two db.Model classes?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a flask app that uses SQLAlchemy to migrate and upgrade a database. The code for initializing the app looks like this:

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config)

    register_extensions(app)
    register_resources(app)

    return app


def register_extensions(app):
    db.init_app(app)
    migrate = Migrate(app, db)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)
    jwt.init_app(app)
```

One of my model classes looks like this:

```
from extensions import db


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(200))
    is_active = db.Column(db.Boolean(), default=False)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime(), nullable=False, server_default=db.func.now())
    updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime(), nullable=False, server_default=db.func.now(), 
onupdate=db.func.now())

    @classmethod
    def get_by_username(cls, username):
        return cls.query.filter_by(username=username).first()

    @classmethod
    def get_by_email(cls, email):
        return cls.query.filter_by(email=email).first()

    @classmethod
    def get_by_id(cls, id):
        return cls.query.filter_by(id=id).first()

    def save(self):
        db.session.add(self)
        db.session.commit()
```

The other model class looks like this:

```
from extensions import db


class Cow(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'cow'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    age = db.Column(db.Numeric)
    sex = db.Column(db.String(1))
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime(), nullable=False, server_default=db.func.now())
    updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime(), nullable=False, server_default=db.func.now(), 
onupdate=db.func.now())

    @classmethod
    def get_all(cls):
        return cls.query.all()

    @classmethod
    def get_all_alive(cls):
        # filter dead yaks
        herd = cls.query.all()
        return

    def save(self):
        db.session.add(self)
        db.session.commit()

    def delete(self):
        db.session.delete(self)
        db.session.commit()
```

My directory structure is as follows:

```
-root
    - models
        -user.py
        -cow.py
    -app.py
    -extensions.py
```

When I run flask db init and flask db migrate, the user table is created in the postgresql datatbase, but the cow table is not. What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please show your project directory structure? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe sure, I just edited to include the directory structure. I don't think that's the issue, because I had a similar project where the second model had a foreign key constraint to the id column of the user table, and both tables were created by flask. This particular case is strange because only the first model is turned into a table.

Comment: Update: After moving both model classes to the first file in the models directory, both tables are created in the database. This seems very bizarre, because there was no need for the models in my other project to be in the same file, and the only difference was that there was backreference in one model to the foreign key constraint in the other one. It seems when the models are linked like this, flask-migrate looks for the other models in the directory, but when they're not it doesn't bother. Seems like a bug but I'm going to research a little more to rule out a configuration mixup on my part.